How to upload a pdf into a url link
I have a pdf that is too big to send in the email system I am using (beacon) because it contains several pictures from photographs .  I would to turn it into a URL so I can send it as a link. How can I do this with Ubuntu?

@kyodake Please post this as an answer

Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Try this:
Open a free account on some site like Mediafire/4share/Dropbox/Google Drive, etc..
Host the pdf on it.
Copy its URL and share it for download.

I found a way to convert a PDF to URL using with Google Drive - it allowed my to upload my PDF powerpoint with pictures and send it as a URL
